# digital logic gates

Tags: digital-logic

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the functionality of a counter. The program I am using is Logisim and I'm trying to implement a counter into my design. I currently have this:

EDITED OUT

What this basically is when K1, K2 or K3 match L1, L2, L3. It opens (LED). I'm wanting to count incorrect attempts of K1, K2, K3 not matching L1, L2, L3 (see problem description below).

I haven't wired the counter(s) yet because I'm not sure how to implement them. My problem is
EDITED OUT

*n* is just in Octal

EDITED OUT

I'm assuming I'm going to need several counters for this problem. Would I need to match outputs of the counters to the X1, X2, X3 decoder?

Comment: If you're just implementing a decoder as a predefined block, you should be able to do the same thing with your counter. What you'll need to do is figure out what logic should drive the enable and reset logic of this counter. Based on the problem description you've given, you don't need more than one counter.

Comment: What do you mean by doing the same thing with my counter?

Comment: What is inside your decoder and selection block?

Comment: Inside my decoder: http://i.imgur.com/2KPwSL2.png Inside my selection: http://i.imgur.com/AXGo3qp.png

Comment: @Vbobo, I meant grab the block from the library and place it in your design, rather than design the counter from gates and flip-flops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your Selection circuit is wrong. It gives false positive, because it needs only one pair of high levels.

Secondly, you do not need to decode your both keys and compare in that form. It is much easier to compare corresponding bits together
[image: compare]

Then you need very similar circuit to this one to compare the Counter value with X1,X2,X3 to check if we already reached max attempts limit
[image: compare counter]
In this example I did a counter of D Flip-flops but you can also use a ready component.

The last part is to connect it all together, I added a button which you should press after entering keys pair.[image: whole circuit]

PermLock simply cuts off button from circuit so its presses are ineffective. All flipflops trigger when the button is pressed and PermLock is not high. It increments counter and updates value of state(open/locked)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was after. Do you have any sources where I can read up more on this? Also. The reason why I used the Decoder is because this particular problem mentioned that BASIC gates can only be used (AND OR and NOT) for the selection part. Sorry I forgot to add that in, but apart from that this is what I was wondering/looking for.

Comment: I think you can learn few things from this http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/ Chapters from 7 to 11. Also XNOR gates used in this example can be built using only AND OR and NOT, create a truth table and try to do same using gates you can use.

Comment: Just one more thing, those counters used are different to the ones I'm using. What does that bubble on the right represent? And is that Clock on the left?

Comment: As I wrote I built a counter using D type flip flops